# If pictureBox is clicked again change size of panel back vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a program that requires a vertical menu bar like in the windows 10 Xbox app. But I'm stuck at the point that if the picturebox is clicked again (after it has been clicked to enlarge the panel) The panel  goes back to the original size. I already used a If statement which checked if the Panel is the enlarged size and then change it back, but it ensured that the panel would not become large. Here's my code:

```
    Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    Panel1.Size = New Size(243, 1080)

    If Panel1.Size = New Size(243, 1080) Then
        Panel1.Size = New Size(81, 1080)
    End If
End Sub
```

But now when i click the picturebox the panel stays the same size.

Comment: hold on ill submit a request to our telepathic department to retrieve the relevant code straight from your brain. you don't even have to post any code in your question!

Comment: here you go, ive added the code

Comment: please post all the relevant code, including the if statement. and please elaborate on the **"but it ensured that the panel would not become large"** part - what do you mean exactly, that the IF statement prevents the panel from becoming large in the first place, or after it goes smaller it will not become large again?

Comment: This sounds like something a lot easier to do with [WPF](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/about-wpf/wpf-vs-winforms/) than WinForms

Comment: I tried using wpf but I found it too hard to use.

Comment: have a look [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.height(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead

```
If Panel1.Size = New Size(243, 1080) Then
```

use

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
    If Panel1.Width = 243 And Panel1.Height = 1080 Then
        Panel1.Size = New Size(81, 1080)
    Else
        Panel1.Size = New Size(243, 1080)
    End If
End Sub
```

And, btw. why not change only `width` when `height` not changing at all (by Your code)...

code :

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.Click
        If Panel1.Width = 243 Then
            Panel1.Width = 81
        Else
            Panel1.Width = 243
        End If
    End Sub
```